# Efficient Partitioning of Numpy Array by Condition

Tags: python, numpy

I recently read the following code that finds the indices within the `ndarray` object `data` where a condition is true, then finds the indices where it was false.

```py
less_idx = np.nonzero(data <= split)
greater_idx = np.nonzero(data > split)
```

Suppose that for some application, these arrays were large and this task was a bottleneck.  Is there a more efficient way to perform this operation in NumPy?  The code above seems to create two temporary copies of what are essentially the same boolean array (up to scalar multiple), then it unnecessarily loops four times over the array `data`  in the course of evaluating the `nonzero` functions (twice for counting numbers of elements, twice for populating the arrays of indices).

Comment: You could avoid using nonzero, do only the first line and use [np.logical_not](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_not.html) for the complement... then perhaps it would be faster to use it as a boolean mask, or get the indices with nonzero later on if it is absolutely necessary

Comment: I doubt you can get it any faster, but [np.less](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.less.html) gives you the option of an additional `where` clause... just to keep in mind

Comment: @RichieV I did try to construct only one copy of the boolean array, then used `np.logical_not` to modify it in place instead of constructing it again.  This did produce some savings, but was only in the neighborhood of 10% faster

Comment: That's as good as it gets, but do consider avoiding nonzero, it is two extra calls that can be worked around if you index with boolean mask directly